# knockout databind with jqueryUI based dateRangePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, daterangepicker

I'm using a jQuery UI based [dateRangePicker](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/) which I am trying to bind with a KnockoutJS based viewModel via a custom binder. But I am not even able to make the dateRangePicker read an observable like

```
this.range = ko.observable("Jul 1,2015 - Jul 3,2015");
```

Here is my  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harsh611/ypu4c01z/9/) attempt. Is that a wrong approach and do I need create something like this

```
this.startDate
this.endDate
```

Comment: in your code you update method missing for the binding handler. Update method will be called when your range observable gets updated.

Comment: @Haridarshan I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/harsh611/ypu4c01z/10/) but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dateRangePicker documentation states that it stores an object with the following properties: `start` and `end`. It stores this as a JSON string in the value field of the `<input>` element that is used to contain dateRangePicker. Therefore, you probably want your `range` observable to also store an object with `start` and `end` properties. I wrote a custom binding which will apply the dateRangePicker to an element and will write the object into your observable any time a different selection is made:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateRangePicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $el = $(element);
        $el.daterangepicker({
            onChange: function() {
                var range = JSON.parse($el.val());
                valueAccessor()(range);
            }
        });
        var value = valueAccessor()();
        if (value) {
            var range = {"start": new Date(value["start"] + " 00:00:00")};
            if (value["end"]) {
                range["end"] = new Date(value["end"] + " 00:00:00");
            }
            $el.daterangepicker("setRange", range);
        }
    }
};
```

You can then apply this to your `<input>` element:

```
<input id="e1" data-bind="dateRangePicker: range">
```

If you need to initialize the value on the dateRangePicker through the viewmodel, then you need to store an object into the `range` observable that matches the format that the dateRangePicker uses:

```
this.range = ko.observable({start:"2015-07-01", end:"2015-07-03"});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efywmomz/

#### Update

I altered the custom binding to use the moment library and updated the fiddle to initialize the `range` from the viewmodel: http://jsfiddle.net/efywmomz/1/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateRangePicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $el = $(element);
        $el.daterangepicker({
            onChange: function() {
                var range = JSON.parse($el.val());
                valueAccessor()(range);
            }
        });
        var value = valueAccessor()();
        if (value) {
            var range = {"start": moment(value["start"])._d};
            if (value["end"]) {
                range["end"] = moment(value["end"])._d;
            }
            $el.daterangepicker("setRange", range);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample which i've implemented with moment js library and daterangepicker js library with knockout

**HTML**

```
<div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" data-bind="BindRangeDatePicker: Value">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value" readonly />
    <span data-bind="text: Value"></span><b class="caret"></b>
</div>
```

**knockout**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.BindRangeDatePicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, context) {
            $(element).daterangepicker(
                {
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
                        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                        'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
                    },
                    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
                    endDate: moment()
                }, function (start, end) {
                    $(element).find('span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                }
            );
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, context) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            $(element).daterangepicker(
                {
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
                        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                        'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
                    },
                    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
                    endDate: moment()
                }, function (start, end) {
                    //var val = start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY');
                    //valueAccessor(val.toString());
                    $(element).find('span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using which datepicker library have u implemented this?

Comment: Dangrossman's daterangepicker library and moment js library https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Comment: I am trying assign a single date [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jtj7kemj/13/) even that is not working